# Get params of parent router

Tags: node.js, express

Assume that I have 2 routers nested together like so:

```
var appRouter = express.Router();
var childRouter = express.Router();

appRouter.use('/:parentId/childpath', childRouter);
childRouter.get('/:childId', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.params); //only childId
    // How do I get parentId ?
});
```

Is there any way to get `parentId` in sub-router handler ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create the child router with

```
express.Router({ mergeParams: true })
```

Comment: How did I miss that xD

Comment: just what i was looking for.